# Could not load nvidia-uvm

Tags: nvidia, cuda

I want to use CUDA on my pc (using bumblebee), but whenever I want to start a cuda-driven program, I get the error `modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia-uvm not found.` I already installed `nvidia-337-uvm` via `apt-get`, but nvidia-modprobe can not find the module. So, what am I doing wrong? System is Ubuntu 14.04.
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the same problem on my machine, I find the solution here:

Edit the file /etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf or create a new file if you are not using bumblebee and add a line to it:

```
alias nvidia-uvm nvidia-340-uvm
```

You should replace nvidia-340-uvm into the version you are using. You can find it by

```
sudo updatedb
locate --regex nvidia-.*-uvm.ko
```

Comment: I have no bumblebee.conf

Answer (score 5):

Thank you! But my string differs:

```
alias nvidia-uvm nvidia_352_uvm
```

Because:

```
$ locate --regex nvidia.*uvm.ko
/lib/modules/3.19.0-39-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia_352_uvm.ko
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-352/352.63/3.19.0-39-generic/x86_64/module/nvidia_352_uvm.ko
```

Maybe it will help anybody more.

Answer (score 1):

Today, I came across a day fulfilled of PURGES and APTITUDE/APT-GET's.
I was trying to fix the problem of activating the nvidia-uvm.

I have a CUDA 6.5 already installed.
I updated my nvidia to 352 thinking that the 340 was with problems.
But as you will see, it was a matter of activating components blacklisted by the bumblebee.

I run:

sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia

However, I decide to comment the following from file "/etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf":

## Workaround to make sure nvidia-uvm is removed as well

## remove nvidia rmmod nvidia-uvm nvidia (commentted)

It was giving problems in my modprobe activation.
First of all, I do not know why, but I have to, always, run the optirun command with some process and, then,
execute sudo modprobe nvidia-XXX-uvm

EX:
"sudo optirun glxspheres64
sudo modprobe nvidia-352-uvm"

I think it is because bumblebee blocks some component that should be activated when optirun is executed.
Anyway, it worked for me and I hope can save some PURGE/INSTALL that everyone maybe be tired of executing.

Best wishes,