# alias nvidia_352_uvm to nvidia-uvm, opencl working only with sudo

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, bumblebee, opencl

I'm using the module `nvidia-352` with `bumblebee` in my ubuntu 14.04. OpenGL programs are working fine with optirun. Nonetheless, bumblebee fails to load the module `nvidia_352_uvm` which is necessary for opencl (and probably cuda, but I don't use it). So, based on [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/525883/269279) I added in `/etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf` the following alias:

```
alias nvidia-uvm nvidia_352_uvm
```

This is half-working. `optirun` is not working but `sudo optirun` is working. Thus, my opencl programs or the command `clinfo` and `darktable -d opencl`, they all need to be runned with `sudo optirun` instead of only `optirun` to work. So, there's some permission that I'm not able to see.

```
$ optirun lsmod | grep nvidia  # same output with $ sudo optirun
nvidia               8642880  25 
drm                   303102  6 i915,drm_kms_helper,nvidia
```

As for a bit of information about my `nvidia_352_uvm`.

```
$ modinfo nvidia_352_uvm 
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-68-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia_352_uvm.ko
supported:      external
license:        MIT
srcversion:     A347F556C35EE8E88DF9DEB
depends:        nvidia
vermagic:       3.13.0-68-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           NVuvm_prefetch_stats:int
parm:           NVuvm_prefetch_threshold:int
parm:           NVuvm_prefetch_adaptive:int
parm:           NVuvm_prefetch_epoch:int
parm:           NVuvm_prefetch_sparsity_inc:int
parm:           NVuvm_prefetch_sparsity_dec:int
parm:           NVuvm_prefetch:int
```

***Sidenote***: I need to use bumblebee in order to activate the nvidia card only for some processes, I don't want it to be used for all the programs because my laptop gets really hot. That's one reason I'm not using nvidia-prime, since I need to logout and login in order to activate the nvidia card.

**UPDATE**

I realized that when I hit for the first time `sudo optirun` with a program that needs `opencl`, the kernel module device `/dev/nvidia-uvm` is created and after the program finish it's still there, the others `/dev/nvidia0` and `/dev/nvidiactl` disappear as it should be.